# How to write a htaccess to change url but point to actual path internally using regex match

Tags: .htaccess

url = www.example.com/de/abc

I just want to change fix url word 'abc' into fix word  'xyz' for browser compatibility only changed url show in browser. But change url point to actual directory path means
www.example.com/de/xyz will follow internally www.example.com/de/abc.

I used some regex to do this, but not able to get actual solution

How can I do this.

Thanks in advance

---

Code from comment :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de/advertiseWithUs$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /de/unsere-tipps [R=302,L]
```

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de/advertiseWithUs$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) /de/unsere-tipps [R=302,L]

Here I want to say "advertiseWithUs" will show browser like "unsere-tipps" its changed but get 404 error because I am redirecting it to new url, which is not correct.  After change it should be follow "de/advertiseWithUs" path.

I hope this will help you.

Thanks in adnvace.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood what you want, here a solution you can try :

```
RewriteRule ^de/advertiseWithUs$ http://yourdomain.com/de/unsere-tipps [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^de/unsere-tipps$ de/advertiseWithUs [NC,L]
```

The first rule change URL (with a 302 redirection), the second one make the internal redirection to point to the right page.

Comment: No Its not working

I am getting "This webpage has a redirect loop" in chrome and in mozila "The page isn't redirecting properly"

I have also cleared cache and cookies but still I am getting this.

Comment: I have removed a slash in the second rule, give it a try now.

Comment: Now according to you its should be 

RewriteRule ^de/advertiseWithUs$ http://yourdomain.com/de/unsere-tipps [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^de/unsere-tipps$ /de/advertiseWithUs [NC,L]

No its not working

Comment: No, I removed a leading slash in the second rule, look carefully

Comment: It will be

RewriteRule ^de/unsere-tipps$ de/advertiseWithUs [NC,L] 

??

Comment: It is giving same response ;-)

Comment: can any one help on this ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi okio can you please back on this with some more solutions